# Get url param in django

Tags: python, django

I have this view:

```
@login_required
def newAnswer(request, id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
    form = AnswerForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.author = request.user
            obj.post = post
            obj.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return redirect('main:post', id=post.id)
        else:
            return render(request, 'main/newAnswer.html', { 'form': form, 'formErrors': form.errors, 'userAvatar': getAvatar(request.user)})
    else:
        return render(request, 'main/newAnswer.html', {'form': form, 'post': post, 'userAvatar': getAvatar(request.user)})
```

When i try to post without loging in, it redirects me to "/accounts/login?next=/post/answer/new/81".

My question is how can i get the "next" param in my login view

thanks!

Comment: use `request.POST.get('next', None)`

Comment: @mahdilotfi it didn't work

Comment: it's GET, not POST...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything arguments (params) you can see in url mean that request is done with `GET` method. Use `request.GET.get('next', None)`.